Bearer Token authentication in .NET 8: how to make token smaller
I am developing a .NET 8 Web API app that uses the new "bearer token" authentication option to authenticate users via a token, like this:
services.AddAuthentication(BearerTokenDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddBearerToken(options =>
    {
        options.BearerTokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    });

and then I log in users and generate the bearer token like this:
var userClaimsPrincipal = ... //generate claims principal
var token = Results.SignIn(userClaimsPrincipal);

This in itself works correctly, however I have an issue with my deployment environment that makes it problematic: the company proxy that is in use where I need to deploy this app blocks HTTP requests that have headers that are over a certain length. And in my case, some users have so many claims (due to extensive use of AD groups in this organization) that their token becomes too large and the request gets blocked.
Unfortunately, I do not have control over how the proxy is configured, so I need to find a solution to make the token smaller.
At the moment my idea for a workaround would be to limit the number of claims I include in the token, since I know my app is only interested in some of them, but I would be interested in knowing if there are more "proper" solutions.
For example, is it possible to store the claims server-side, and in the token only include an ID that is then used server-side to fetch the claims for that user? Or is there any other built-in mechanism that does something like this, before I waste time implementing a custom ClaimsProvider or something like that?

You are using IdTokens  between UI & API and basically reading claims from the token itself, right?
you can also consider switching to AcceessToken which is really small and build your authorization based on that. Another option is to use from API Introspection endpoint which can return your claims based on initial token from UI

I don't need the claims ui-side, I'm only using them to authorize access to specific controller methods server-side. What would be the best approach in this case?

You should check if your OIDC server supports access tokens in introspect endpoint, and is supports load claims directly from API https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/introspection.html

UI can send accessTokens (just about 20 symbols) instead of long IdToken

I'm using Microsoft Entra ID as authentication provider, I would like to avoid messing with the token configuration if possible because the same App Registration is used by other applications in production, that's why I was searching for a solution to implement in my backend.
